# SharePoint Online Communication Site-Code Snippet Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site, snippet

I am trying to use the code snippet webpart on a SharePoint Online Page. In order to test, I have written a single Header Tag

### Heading

but for some reason it doesn't render on the page. It only shows the code on the page.

Is there any way to make the code render on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `code editor web part` is specifically designed to show source code on the web page.

So what you're seeing is by design. If you'd like to enter HTML to be displayed, there is no OOTB method that I'm aware of.

One option is to create a custom **SPFx** part, which enables to you render any HTML you want.

Of course, this is not a trivial undertaking and requires a developer skill set.